# Memorizing chemical equations

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Is there's an easy or at least a practical solution for memorizing chemical equations? I'm currently in grade 12 and we're studying a whole chapter about Iron and how to prepare it, starting from the Iron ore till converting it to different Iron compounds used in the industry, and we have questions in the exams like `How can you obtain Iron(II) sulfide from Iron(II) oxide`, we have about 25 equations that should be memorized in order to solve such question!

Comment: We don't memorize equations. We memorize the general rules.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So what are those rules? where should I start from?

Comment: Why should you memorize them when you can write them yourself. In this case  of obtaining Iron(II) sulfide from Iron(II) oxide there are various ways like reacting the Iron(II) oxide with Hydrogen Sulfide (H2S) etc.

Comment: Your teacher should have taught you those rules. How oxidation numbers work, stochiometry, Budouard reaction, etc. Then you just memorise the general picture of the blast furnace process, and the equations fall into place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question. Memorization is difficult. I'm a chemist, and I try not to memorize, but just stuff stuff into my memory. As Ivan said, you memorize the rules.

But I'm going to go one step further: in your imagination (because that's the only lab and production space available to you for this exercise), get a ton of iron ore (in whatever compounds are listed) and convert them into the various products that are desired. In other words, immerse yourself into the chemistry.

There are not 25 equations; there are about 10 compounds and about 50 ways to combine them, only some of which are reasonable. The unreasonable combinations are as interesting as the reasonable ones. Why don't some things happen? Why do some things go neatly? When you stack the 10 compounds up in columns or rows and draw lines between them, you have a road map - that you have traversed backwards and forwards! You have drawn an image that is engraved in long-term memory rather than memorize a list in short-term memory.

I think this enables you to become a chemist more easily. If you can't do it this way, hard work and memorizing the equations will probably get you thru the course with a good grade, but I bet you'll forget most of it within a year.